# I want to prevent Direct IP is not allowed

Tags: javascript

I'm so sorry, I want this feature
I don't have info on it to give you an example
But there is another site that uses it
From here: http://135.125.251.122
If you enter through IP, the site says Direct IP is not allowed
Then it automatically brings me to the domain

All I found is this code

```
<script language="JavaScript">window.alert("Direct IP is not allowed")</script><script language="JavaScript">window.open("https://example.com", "_self")</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Mohamed, your question is not related with javascript. What you're asking can be done using an nginx server. An example can be found here: https://pieterbakker.com/disable-direct-ip-access-in-nginx-http-https/

Comment: Actually its done by almost *every* webserver - IIS, nginx, apache, lighttpd, g-wan.... But it's trivial to write javascript which reads the window.location and amends the content accordingly or to write CSS using the :host pseudo class.